# Sinatra and PostgreSQL - running the entire database and app

Tags: sql, postgresql, sinatra

I have been  struggling with rerunning my apps from MAC OS to my windows OS. I have never liked databases. Anyway, the thing is that I cannot even load up my seeds. It looks like it cannot run the pg gem methods. Here's my error

```
:in `ensure in run': undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

here's the code the method gets stuck on

```
require_relative('../models/collection')
require_relative('../models/product')
require('pry')

Product.delete_all()
Collection.delete_all()


fw2015 = Collection.new({
 'name' => 'Fall Winter 2015/2016'
 })

fw2015.add()
```

I am pretty sure that it's something with postgres. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a gem issue, not a PostgreSQL issue.  It is probably relating to the fact that there are binary portions of the gem and they may not be building right.  So you need to make sure that you have the PostgreSQL client libraries and header files installed, and that you have all necessary compilers.

Try uninstalling and re-installing the gem and see what errors and warnings show up.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling the pg gem and I get the same errors when running seeds.rb file. I have tried to install postgreSQL on my windows os laptop so maybe it's something about running the database itself?

Comment: Nope, everything goes well with the installation